# React 404 Heroku Issue

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have a strange issue. I have two separate Heroku apps (staging, production) both deploying the exact same code in the same environment, with the same buildpacks.

Everything works fine, except that on the production app 404 errors are showing the generic Nginx 404 instead of the 404 page from the react application.

The 404 page works as intended in the staging application.

I am just serving the React app, and I'm using the [Create React App Buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack). I've tried redeploying, restarting, etc. and I have no idea what's happening.

Has anyone experienced anything similar to this?

Answer (score -1):

Change your static.json file as follows

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "routes":{
      "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

You could have messed with the build folders name